# How does signed byte sent from java application will arrive on arduino expecting unsigned byte?

Tags: java, android, c++, bluetooth, arduino

My simple java application sends two bytes to arduino over bluetooth. One byte `0x0A` and second byte will be 0xA0, or 0xA1, or 0xB0, or 0xB1...

Here is how two bytes are sent from java

```
public static byte RELAY_ACCESSORIES_OFF    = (byte)0xB0;
public static byte RELAY_ACCESSORIES_ON     = (byte)0xB1;
...
connection.Send(new byte[] {0x0A, RELAY_ACCESSORIES_ON});
    else
connection.Send(new byte[] {0x0A, RELAY_ACCESSORIES_OFF});
```

And arduino just reads incoming data as a unsigned byte. 
So how does this signed and unsigned byte work out between java and arduino?

Comment: I don't think there is anything as a signed / unsigned byte.   It's a byte, 8 bits, period.   Do you mean the arduino is only picking up one byte and not the array?   What class is connection from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usigned and signed integer values (of the same size) are represented by the same bit patterns, the only difference lies in their interpretation. There is no such thing as a signed or unsigned byte when you reduce it to the pure binary representation.

A signed byte from a java can be transmitted just fine to a receiver that treats it as unsigned. Problem only commonly arise because the programmer is not aware of the very different behavior achieved depening on signed/unsigned when a byte its cast to a larger type (which is common in java to happen implicitly in practically *any* operation you can perform on a byte, since java operators like +, -, *, == are defined to operate alaways on the 32-bit sign extended value of a byte).

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to know. I remember professor saying something about different data types on different machines represented by different bit patterns.

Comment: Well your professor is right :) With larger types you have to worry about *byte order* (aka. endianess), or with floating point numbers your have to worry about which format they are in (there exist some older formats than IEEE754, mainly used by legacy platforms, DEC and PDP had different implementations IIRC). And there is *one* and *twos* complement representation for integers (the former practically extinct nowadays).